# How do I format my theorem environment to fit the itemize?

Tags: itemize, minipage, mdframed, amsthm

I study by making summaries of books, and, in order to prevent constructing a narrative, I use the itemize environment to break up chapters, sections and subsections into the essential information. However, the books I study contain a lot of mathematical theorems which I'd like to display in an neat way that stands out.

This is the desired result:
[image: Desired result]
I cannot seem to figure out how to construct a working theorem environment that can correctly be used in the itemize environment.

My preamble is as follows:

```
\documentclass[9pt,fleqn]{extarticle}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, hmargin=64pt, top=72pt, bottom=72pt, headsep=24pt, footskip=24pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools, thmtools}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
    \definecolor{l_gray}{gray}{0.84}
    \definecolor{d_gray}{gray}{0.48}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed}

\setitemize{topsep=0pt, itemsep=0pt, leftmargin=16pt}
\setenumerate{topsep=0pt, itemsep=0pt, leftmargin=16pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.64\baselineskip}    

\def\labelitemi{--}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiii}{--}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiv}{--}
```

Now, there are a few ways in which I have tried to accomplish the desired result.

This approach seemed to yield the best result:

```
\declaretheoremstyle[
    headfont=\scseries, 
    notebraces={[}{]},
    bodyfont=\normalfont,
    headpunct={.},
    postheadspace=\newline,
    postheadhook={\textcolor{d_gray}{\rule[.6ex]{\linewidth}{0.4pt}}\\},
    spacebelow=0pt,
    spaceabove=0pt,
    mdframed={
        backgroundcolor=l_gray!80, 
            linecolor=l_gray,
            roundcorner=0pt, 
            innertopmargin=4pt,
            innerbottommargin=4pt,
            innerleftmargin=4pt,
            innerrightmargin=4pt,
            skipabove=0pt, 
            skipbelow=0pt} 
]{sumstyle}

\declaretheorem[
    style=sumstyle,
    name=Theorem,
    numberwithin=section
]{innertheorem}

\newenvironment{theorem}{\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\begin{innertheorem}}{\end{innertheorem}\end{minipage}}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[1]
    \item
    \begin{theorem}
        Suppose that
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item $f$ is piecewise continuous on the interval $0 \leq t \leq A$ for any positive $A$.
            \item $\left| f \left( t \right) \right| \leq K e^{a t}$ when $t \geq M$. In this inequality, $K$, $a$, and $M$ are real constants, $K$ and $M$ necessarily positive.
        \end{enumerate}
        Then the Laplace transform $\mathcal{L} \left\{ f \left( t \right) \right\} = F \left( s \right)$, defined by Eq. \ref{eq:0601_04_LaPlaceTrans}, exists for $s > a$.
    \end{theorem}
    \item \lipsum[1]
\end{itemize}
```

However, creating a minipage out of a mdframed (and theorem) environment seems wrong.
Maybe I am taking a totally wrong approach, I don't know. I look forward to any replies!

I am new to StackExchange and I hope I have provided enough information. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you incorporate the bullet into the theorem label?

Comment: and end the itemize before beginning the theorem?

Comment: Yes.  Is this a problem?

Comment: I think it will be when an item consists of text and a theorem, respectively. I would like to stay inside the itemize environment, but mdframed does not seem to play nice with that. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Another solution would be to have the bullets in the left margin and to use a package like `thmtools` which lets you easily customise the layout of theorems.

Comment: The problem of mdframed and itemize not playing nice together can be negated by completely letting go of mdframed altogether (since itemize is essential for my purposes). However, thmtools does not offer the extensive customizability mdframed offers.Thanks for the advice, I'll try to get the hang of using solely thmtools.

Comment: Anyway, `thmtools` can wor=k with `mdframed` as well with `tcolorbox`. From the image you posted, I would say the simpler `framed` package would be enough.